# Apply Jsvascript in shopify parallex theme but script is not working properly

Tags: jquery, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

By default "BUY IT  NOW" button is disabled. I need this also on page load

1. When we select "Slab" then enable "BUY IT NOW" button.
2. When we select "Pre-Hung" then disable "BUY IT NOW" button and same in case of "Jamb Sizes" options "BUY IT NOW" button is disabled.
3. But when user click on any option from DOOR HANDLING then enable "BUY IT NOW" button.

**Problem:**

I have done this work with jquery. My jquery is working in google inspect element console. But in shopify theme liquid files jquery is working but in rare cases. I am trying it many times.

**Screenshots:**

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKgeM.png), [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NtUU.png)

**My jquery code:**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="properties[DOOR OPTION]"]').on('input change', function 
      () {
        if ($(this).val() != 'Pre-Hung') {
          alert('ggg');
            $('.add_to_cart').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
          $('.add_to_cart').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
  $('input[name="properties[DOOR HANDING]"]').on('input change', function () 
   {
        $('.add_to_cart').prop('disabled', false);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You were binding the change event twice, with contradicting effects. I don't know Shopify and I am not absolutely sure about your intentions yet but I guess that you should start with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('input change','input[name="properties[DOOR OPTION]"]', 
    function() {
      $('.add_to_cart').prop('disabled',$(this).val() != 'Pre-Hung');
    });
 });
```